# Docker container --tls-min-v1.0 is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to run a Kibana docker container.

When I launch it I get this error

> /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node: --tls-min-v1.0 is not allowed
> in NODE_OPTIONS

I cannot see any options being specified. I thought I cracked it when I noted that this option is only available in NODE > 12.00

I upgraded the container to use NODE 12.3.1 but the problem persists.

Has anyone come across this before, and if so how did you go about fixing it?

Comment: If you run `node --version` inside the container, which version does it output?

Comment: 12.3.1, albeit this is the ARM8 version. I'm trying to kick it forward to 14.4 this morning and see if that helps. Maybe this option lags behind the ARM8 world?

Comment: I'd be surprised to hear that! Is it possible that the binary Kibana is trying to run is an old Node version? That there's multiple versions? Does the flag work if you manually run Node inside the container with that option in NODE_OPTIONS?